# Retrieving HashMap from TreeMap

Tags: java, hashmap, treemap

I use following complex data structure.

```
departures = new TreeMap<String,  Map<String,  Set<MyObject>>>();
arrivals=new HashMap<String, Set<MyObject>>();
flights=new HashSet<MyObject>();
```

Then I use loops (I also tried other loops).

```
for(String dep: nizDep){
    for(String arr: nizArr){
      for(MyObject flight: _flights){
        if(flight.getFrom().equalsIgnoreCase(dep)&&flight.getTo().equalsIgnoreCase(arr)){
                    flights.add(flight);
                 }
                }
                if(!flights.isEmpty()){
            arrivals.put(arr, flights);
                    flights.clear();
                    }
            }
            if(!arrivals.isEmpty()){
            departures.put(dep, arrivals);
            arrivals.clear();
            }
    }
    System.out.println(departures.size()); //result 14
    System.out.println(departures.containsKey("Madrid")); //result true
            arrivals=departures.get("Madrid");
    System.out.println(arrivals.size()); //result 0, arrivals is empty. WHY?
```

My question is how to use this complex data structure and how to retrieve arrivals from departures?

Comment: Why are you not making classes for this 'complex structure'?  If you did, it would make it a little more understandable...

Comment: because this is a part of a lot bigger project which i need to finish and some code i don't supposed to change (for example this data structure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     System.out.println(arrivals.size()); //result 0, arrivals is empty. WHY?
```

**BECAUSE** When you call `flights.clear();` after `arrivals.put(arr, flights);` or `arrivals.clear();` after `departures.put(dep, arrivals);`, this clears your original objects(flights and arrivals). Please bring your initialization statements i.e.

```
        Map<String, Set<MyObject>> arrivals=new HashMap<String, Set<MyObject>>();
        Set<MyObject>(); flights=new HashSet<MyObject>();
```

within the `for` loops **or replace that statement as below:**

```
                if(!flights.isEmpty()){
                   Set<MyObject> newflights=new HashSet<MyObject>(); 
                    newflights.addAll(flights); //copy elements to new set
                   arrivals.put(arr, newflights);
                    flights.clear();
                }
```

Same you may do with `departures`.

**Now for retrievals:**

```
      Set<String> arrivalKeys = departures.keySet();
      Interator<String> arrIter = arrivalKeys.iterator();
      while(arrIter.hasNext()){
        String arrKey = arrIter.next();
        Map<String, Set<MyObject>> arrivals = departures.get(arrKey );
        //use your arrivals map object
      }
```

Same you can do to retrieve `flights` from `arrivals` e.g.

for each arrivals retrieved as above:

```
      Set<String> flightKeys = arrivals.keySet();
      Interator<String> flIter = flightKeys.iterator();
      while(flIter.hasNext()){
        String flKey = flIter.next();
        Set<MyObject> flights = arrivals.get(flKey );
        //use your flights set object
      }
```

Comment: wouldn't for loop instead of using iterator make code less verbose and easy?

Answer (score 0):

```
arrivals=new HashMap<String, Set<MyObject>>();
departures = new TreeMap<String,  Map<String,  Set<MyObject>>>();
for(String dep: nizDep){
    for(String arr: nizArr){
      for(MyObject flight: _flights){
        if(flight.getFrom().equalsIgnoreCase(dep)&&flight.getTo().equalsIgnoreCase(arr)){
            flights=new HashSet<MyObject>(); 
            flights.add(flight);        
            arrivals.put(arr, flights);     
            departures.put(dep, arrivals);
         }
      }
   }
}
System.out.println(departures.size()); //result 14
if(departures.containsKey("Madrid")) {
    arrivals=departures.get("Madrid");
    System.out.println(arrivals.size());
}
```

In case you want to keep a one-to-one mapping between arrivals and flights, then this code works. In case you want to keep a global structure of maintaining the set of flights then you'll have to create another global gflights object and put every flights object into it.